# my trigger error in mysql, hen help to fix

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I can't understand why my trigger doesn't work.

first table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Payment` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idPaymentMethod` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updateAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `actived` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `numberInvoices` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preferentialPaymentDay` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoicesFrequency` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `PaymentHistory` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idPaymentMethod` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idPayment` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updateAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `actived` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `numberInvoices` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preferentialPaymentDay` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoicesFrequency` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

my trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER `update_history` AFTER
UPDATE
    ON
    `Payment` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE
    `PaymentHistory`
SET
    id = OLD.id,
    idPaymentMethod = old.idPaymentMethod,
    createAt = old.createAt,
    updateAt = old.updateAt,
    actived = old.actived,
    numberInvoices = old.numberInvoices

END$$
```

I get a lot of errors when I try to fix something.

Errors I get:

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END$$' at line 1

SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'OLD.id' in 'field list'

I am really lost.

I need all the updated data in the "Payment" table to be inserted or updated into the "PaymentHistory" table

Plase, i need a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to finish each command with a semicolon

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER `update_history` AFTER
UPDATE
    ON
    `Payment` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE
    `PaymentHistory`
SET
    id = OLD.id,
    idPaymentMethod = old.idPaymentMethod,
    createAt = old.createAt,
    updateAt = old.updateAt,
    actived = old.actived,
    numberInvoices = old.numberInvoices;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa65cc0c8fbf549d19514bf134002c37)

Answer (score 0):

first, thanks to @nbk

i solved with yours help

i change de "after" to "before" and add the ";"

see;

```
TRIGGER `update_history` BEFORE
UPDATE
    ON
    `Payment` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE
    `PaymentHistory`
SET
     idPayment = old.id
    , idPaymentMethod = old.idPaymentMethod
    , createAt = old.createAt
    , updateAt = old.updateAt
    , actived = old.actived
    , numberInvoices = old.numberInvoices;

END
```

Comment: an update without a WHERE clause will update **every** row, so you should fix that and it doesn't really matter if you make a before or after, the outcome is the same